# GridView Column Size when using Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

My problem is some of my table columns not completely visible.I want to make auto size column width.

```
settings.Columns.Add(c =>
        {
            c.FieldName = "Customer_Mail";
            c.Caption = "Customer Mail";
            c.Settings.FilterMode = ColumnFilterMode.DisplayText;
            c.Width=??; // -> Here is the problem I think
        });
```

Comment: As far as I know 'AutoWidth' is the default behaviour until you set either the width of the grid or its column. Check out [this question](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q432109/aspxgridview-autowidth-column)

Comment: When I add horizontal scrollbar columns get jamming.I add fixed width all of them.

Answer (score 0):

When using any of the [Fixed Table Layout](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/9316/ASP-NET-WebForms-Controls/Grid-View/Concepts/Focus-and-Navigation/Paging-and-Scrolling/ASPxGridView-Fixed-Table-Layout-Specifics-Scrolling-and-Column-Resizing) options (such as the Horizontal Scrolling), it is necessary to specify the columns' width manually.